# Processing multiple files from a directory

Tags: matlab

How can i do the same math function(eg:average) for a folder containing large number of data files using matlab(2010) and store them in one output? 
This is the code I have, but it was unsuccessful.

```
function A = RepeatForAll()
A = 0;
% audio is the folder name where audio files are saved
path = fullfile(pwd,'audio');

files = dir(path);

for fileIndex=3:length(files)

    if (files(fileIndex).isdir == 0)
        if (~isempty(strfind(files(fileIndex).name,'wav')))
            fullfile(path,files(fileIndex).name)
            result = wavread(fullfile(path,files(fileIndex).name));

            % Any thing you have to for each audio file
            inputz=wavread(result);
            outx = mfccx(result);

            A(count,:) = mean(outx,2);
            count=count+1;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't find any logical mistake in code....
what exactly made it unsuccessful

Comment: Unsuccessful how? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
count=0;
```

before going into the for loop, now count is undefined.

Also the line `inputz=wavread(result);` is both unused and wrong. you don't use `inputz` anywhere, and you are calling `wavread` on `result`, which is not a filename (see the line above). This would generate an error.

Please be more clear next time, at least give us error messages. Describing what you think should happen is also useful.

Last, correctly format your code. In matlab, select al your code (`control+a`) then press `control+i` to format it.

Comment: Dear Diederick, First of all, "Thank you" for the quick response. I re corrected the code as you mentioned. I want to wavread each file in my "audio" folder and do the function called "mfccx" for each and take the average of each output and store it to a one output. This code reads every file in the "audio" folder but the problem is, it outputs the "mfccx" function only on the last file. That is why it was unsuccessful. How to modify it to fix the problem?

Comment: from your code it seems you are writing a row to A for _each_ processed file, so the current code would not give you output only for the last...